# Google Trends API Contact

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-trends

Trying to get whitelisted for the Google Trends API via Google API Console

Read the resources here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ybu3gHUHtcSXXzgDJ-m7PPto9tw0QG8A5oOBsFP2jao/edit and tried to contact the team via the e-mail address provided

E-mail bounced though, so trying to get whitelisted but can't seem to connect

Any help or shoves in the right direction would be sweet

Tom

Comment: I just had the same issue. Did you find the solution?